# I have Perl5.28 installed and Net::LibIDN installed but amavisd cant find it

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

I'm on a MacMini, using Homebrew to install things.

But - amavisd can't start because apparently it can't find this Net::IDN module?

I'm getting this

```
ERROR: MISSING REQUIRED BASIC MODULES:
Net::LibIDN
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/sbin/amavisd line 251.
```

But I'm sure it is installed.

```
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/install-  0.01.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring install-0.01 ... OK
Building and testing install-0.01 ... OK
Successfully installed install-0.01
Net::LibIDN is up to date. (0.12)
1 distribution installed
```

So how do I tell Perl to find it now?

EDIT:
So I'm forcing a reinstall - but still no joy

```
zeus:~ robert$ sudo cpanm --reinstall Net::LibIDN
Password:
--> Working on Net::LibIDN
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TH/THOR/Net-LibIDN-0.12.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Net-LibIDN-0.12 ... OK
Building and testing Net-LibIDN-0.12 ... OK
Successfully reinstalled Net-LibIDN-0.12
1 distribution installed
zeus:~ robert$
```

and trying to run amavisd ...

```
zeus:~ robert$ sudo /usr/local/sbin/amavisd -c /usr/local/etc/amavisd.conf debug
Password:
ERROR: MISSING REQUIRED BASIC MODULES:
  Net::LibIDN
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/sbin/amavisd line 251.
zeus:~ robert$
```

So for some reason, it seems amavisd-new can't find the module. Just that Module?

Comment: Does the amavisd run in the same perl you installed the library to? Also not that you installed [install](http://p3rl.org/install) (which is fortunately harmless).

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did install “install”.. but yes, I’ve made sure I only have the one version of Perl. Updated to the latest. 5.8 I think it is.

Comment: Where did `cpanm` instlal the module? What's the value of the @INC variable in amavisd before it fails to find the missing module?

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Net/LibIDN.pm and in inc is here i think. add_entropy($], @INC, %ENV);

Comment: I fear `amavisd` uses the system perl.

Comment: You are right! I should have thought of this. I will move the system perl and link the Brew perl there. It has now at least found a different module that is missing... Thanks for that hint

Comment: Oh yes, I changed the shebang line in amavisd to reflect the perl path, from #!/usr/bin/perl to #!/usr/local/bin/perl and now it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `amavisd` uses the system perl, while `cpanm` was installed to a custom perl and installs modules there.

Either install the module to system perl, or try to convince `amavisd` to run in the custom perl (might involve manually changing the shebang lines in its source files).